# WebScarab bean shell debug

Tags: security, security-testing, webscarab

I'm using WebScarab bean shell. Just wondering what's the best way to debug the shell script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at the output in the Messages panel, or in the console (if you started it from a console. e.g. java -jar webscarab.jar). It will give you stack traces that will indicate what went wrong. You can also use System.out.println to emit debugging information.

Of course, you'd be more likely to get better results asking this question on the WebScarab mailing list. See https://lists.owasp.org/mailman/listinfo/owasp-webscarab